# How to upgrade to the last version of a package?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have this composer.json

> ```
> "require": {
>     "php": "^8.0.2",
>     "badaso/core": "^2.5",
>     "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "=7.5.1",
>     "laravel/framework": "^9.11",
>     "laravel/octane": "=1.5.5",
>     "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
>     "laravel/tinker": "^2.7"
> },
> "require-dev": {
>     "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.9",
>     "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
>     "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
>     "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
>     "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
>     "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
>     "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
> },
> ```

but the command "composer update" installs "badaso/code 2.9.4" and not the last version 2.9.8

I ran "composer why-not badaso/core 2.9.8" that returns

> badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          arcanedev/log-viewer (8.1.0)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  arcanedev/log-viewer (but
> 9.0.0 is installed)                 badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          darkaonline/l5-swagger (8.5)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  darkaonline/l5-swagger (but
> 8.3.3 is installed)               badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          symfony/var-exporter (5.4.21)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  symfony/var-exporter (but
> v6.3.2 is installed)                badaso/core     2.9.8  requires
> phpstan/phpstan (1.10.15)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  phpstan/phpstan (but 1.10.27
> is installed)                    badaso/core     2.9.8  requires
> spatie/laravel-backup (7.8)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  spatie/laravel-backup (but
> 8.1.11 is installed)               badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          spatie/laravel-activitylog (4.7.1)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  spatie/laravel-activitylog
> (but 4.7.3 is installed)           badaso/core     2.9.8  requires
> google/apiclient (2.13.2)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  google/apiclient (but v2.15.0
> is installed)                   badaso/core     2.9.8  requires
> spatie/flysystem-dropbox (1.2.3)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  spatie/flysystem-dropbox (but
> 2.0.6 is installed)             badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext (1.3.2)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require
> masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext (but v2.2.2 is installed)
> badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          predis/predis (2.1.2)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  predis/predis (but v1.1.10 is
> installed)                      badaso/core     2.9.8  requires
> zircote/swagger-php (4.7.10)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  zircote/swagger-php (but
> 3.2.0 is installed)                  badaso/core     2.9.8  requires          league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (1.0.29)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
> (but 3.15.0 is installed)          badaso/core     2.9.8  requires
> league/flysystem (1.1.10)
> badaso/starter  -      does not require  league/flysystem (but 3.15.1
> is installed)

but did not see what to do ...

If I change my composer.json with "badaso/core":"^2.9.8", I get this error when I run "composer -W update"

> Problem 1
> - darkaonline/l5-swagger 8.5.0 requires laravel/framework ^10.0 || ^9.0 || >=8.40.0 || ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.11.0,
> ..., 9.x-dev].
> - laravel/framework[v9.36.4, ..., 9.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ...,
> 3.x-dev].
> - laravel/framework[v9.18.0, ..., v9.36.3] require league/flysystem ^3.0.16 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.16,
> ..., 3.x-dev].
> - laravel/framework[v9.11.0, ..., v9.17.0] require league/flysystem ^3.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.0.0, ...,
> 3.x-dev].
> - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: league/flysystem[1.0.0-alpha1, ..., 1.x-dev,
> 2.0.0-alpha.1, ..., 2.x-dev, 3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev].
> - badaso/core[2.9.8, ..., 2.x-dev] require darkaonline/l5-swagger 8.5 -> satisfiable by darkaonline/l5-swagger[8.5.0].
> - badaso/core[2.9.8, ..., 2.x-dev] require league/flysystem 1.1.10 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.10].
> - Root composer.json requires badaso/core ^2.9.8 -> satisfiable by badaso/core[2.9.8, 2.x-dev].

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try composer update -W

Comment: Already done, see my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what's happening is you have other packages that have some dependencies, that prevent that particular version from being installed. There's no real way around this, unfortunately.

Comment: Not wrong but which package since it's a fresh new install?

Comment: Don't understand how this can happen ...

Comment: I don't know, but is there a reason why you need a minor patch version? It looks like it's a version clash with flysystem.

Comment: Thanks, as @Nico Haase wrote I opened an issue in the project https://github.com/uasoft-indonesia/badaso/issues/1018

Answer (score 1):

From [v2.9.4 to v2.9.5](https://github.com/uasoft-indonesia/badaso/compare/2.9.4...2.9.5), the version dependencies changed in a strange way: for some package dependencies, an older version than before is now required. For example, according to the error log you've posted, you are currently using v9.0.0 of the package `arcanedev/log-viewer`, but since v2.9.5, the root package does not support v9, but only the older v8 of that package.

From my point of view, the most strange change is that v2.9.4 allowed the installation of `league/flysystem` v3, but v2.9.5 does no longer. You are required to use `league/flysystem` v1, but this is not compatible with Laravel v9 (which requires v3 of Flysystem).

---

After all, there's little you can change on your own. You cannot resolve these problems in your own application without sideeffects. If you really want to use an updated version of that package, open an issue at the project's issue tracker to get these version problems resolved.

Comment: I opened the issue https://github.com/uasoft-indonesia/badaso/issues/1018. Since @Oddman gave the same root cause a little before I choose his solution but thank youo very much for your detailaid answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to enter "badaso/core": "^2.9" manually in composer.json then run composer update

Comment: Already did this try, redid ir ... no  change.

Comment: then try to enter the version "2.9.8" and see what the problem is.

Comment: Already did this try, post updated with the error resulted.

Answer (score -1):

Try 2 lines:

```
  composer clearcache
  composer upgrade
```

Comment: did these commands, no change.

Comment: Hi @Dri372 If the package is already installed, you must remove it. Only after that should you clear the cache and install the package again.

Comment: Thanks @Emma Ngo for your reply, but what it's strange, is that it's a fresh new project install. It install version 2.9.4 that is not the last version!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it